# Disallow data attribute equality when using data-attr inside Emmet and SublimeText

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

Setting up snippets for lego-like blocks to do rapid production. Inside the snippets is the following code:

```
"menu:drop": "ul.dropdown.menu[data-dropdown-menu]>li*${1:how_many}>a{Item \\$}"
```

However, upon completion in SublimeText, the following is produced:

```
<ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu="">
    <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is anyone aware of a way without hacking the Emmet core script to disallow the '`=""`' after the '`data-dropdown-menu`' attr?

Comment: doesn't look like it: http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a dot after attribute name to make it *boolean*, e.g. `ul.dropdown.menu[data-dropdown-menu.]`. In HTML mode, it will output `<ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>`, but in XML/XHTML the result will be `<ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu="data-dropdown-menu">`.

See http://emmet.io/blog/beta-v1-1/ for more info

Comment: Thanks! I missed that.